# Path pattern for intent-filter

Tags: android, path, intentfilter

I want to launch Android application on clicking URL (may be in e-mail or SMS).

How to write different path patterns for these two URL?

- `http://www.hostname.com/folder1/file.ext`
- `http://www.hostname.com/folder1/folder2/file.ext`

I want to launch my activity only from the first URL, not the second one. Currently I am using this `intent-filter` but it's launching my app with both URL.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="www.hostname.com"
        android:pathPattern=".*\\/folder1/*"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="www.hostname.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/folder1"
        android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```